# JSON: loop Invoice Items : add if InvoiceNo not exits, update value if it does, example included

Tags: javascript, json, loops, items

I'm trying to loop through a list of Invoices, and their Individual LineItem Values,
and in the end have an Ojbect of [object Arrays] with an Invoice Number and the total value for all line items per Invoice.

```
var objInvoiceLineItem = function (strInvoiceNo,strValue) {
    this.InvoiceNo= strInvoiceNo;
    this.Value = strValue;
}
```

//

```
var objAllInvoices = [];
```

//

```
function AddValueTo_objAllInvoices(myInvoice){
    //don't know how to look and see if the Invoice exists? 
     //jQuery.inArray? 
     //for (var i = 0; i < objAllInvoices.length - 1; i++)?

    if exists (myInvoice.InvoiceNo) = false{
     var newObjInvoiceItem= 
          new objInvoiceLineItem(myInvoice.InvoiceNo, myInvoice.Value);
         objAllInvoices.push(newObjInvoiceItem)
    }
    else{
          //need help here please
         var obj = getobject;
         objAllInvoices.obj.Value += myInvoice.Value;
    }  
}
```

//

```
var Invoice1A = new objInvoiceLineItem("Invoice1",20);
var Invoice1B = new objInvoiceLineItem("Invoice1",50);
var Invoice2A = new objInvoiceLineItem("Invoice2",30);


AddValueTo_objAllInvoices(Invoice1A);
AddValueTo_objAllInvoices(Invoice1B);
AddValueTo_objAllInvoices(Invoice2A);
```

Comment: Need to ask a specific question for people to know how to help.

Comment: Apologies, I need some help on checking whether the Item already exists in ObjAllInvoices[] please, I think I will be able to update the Invoice.Value when I get help on the existence of an object. Thank you

Comment: Is the InvoiceNo always guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this will do what you want:

```
function AddValueTo_objAllInvoices(myInvoice)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < objAllInvoices.length; i++)
    {
        if (objAllInvoices[i].InvoiceNo == myInvoice.InvoiceNo)
        {
            // invoice exists, update it and return
            objAllInvoices[i].Value += myInvoice.Value;
            return;
        }
    }

    // if the invoice already existed, we would have returned in the loop
    // so we wouldn't have ever gotten here, so the invoice must not exist.
    // create it now:
    var newObjInvoiceItem = new objInvoiceLineItem(myInvoice.Container, myInvoice.Value);
    objAllInvoices.push(newObjInvoiceItem);
}
```